# Floating desk strength

Tags: wood, carpentry, joinery

I have a built in floating desk in my new house which the previous owners installed. The desk I believe is made from MDF with 2 brackets holding it to the wall, also wood but not sure what type. The desk is 3.30m in length, 62cm depth and 4cm thick. From what I can see the brackets are attached to the wall at 4 points with large screws, the wall is plaster board external wall. I have a desktop PC and a 22 Litre fish tank currently on it. I want to add another 80litre tank. Will this be strong enough to support the weight? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want to add 100kg… what happens if you sit on it?

Comment: Would depend on how those brackets are mounted to the wall.  Are they screwed into the studs or just anchors into the plaster?  How those brackets are made?  Placement of the bigger tank on the shelf?    That size of a tank, I would think about adding supports from the shelf to the floor.

Comment: It depends on the location of the tank.  Back up against the wall?  Could be OK.  On the front edge?  Less likely to be OK.

Answer (score 4):

Previous owner's home-built brackets?

I would not risk it. Maybe if you replaced the wooden brackets with fully triangulated steel brackets of **known** load capacity sufficient for the loading.

Aquarium disasters are no fun, and adding a computer to the mix makes it even less fun.

If you are determined to try it, move the computer and small fish tank to a different location, and put something like sandbags somewhat exceeding the planned load on for at least a couple of weeks, to see it it holds with something that won't make a huge mess if it does not. Make some witness marks and examine closely for any shifting or movement short of total collapse.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I would swap the wooden brackets with what I call "[max brackets](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51b77fMRKcL._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg)". Then you're golden. [More info](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/151312/35141)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description and rough translation into ugly American units of measure, I'm fairly certain those brackets are secured either into studs or into brick/block behind the drywall. The top (4cm ~ 1.5") is thick enough and the brackets *look* sturdy. But another 80 litre? That's around 180 lbs., maybe a bit more including the tank itself. I would (carefully, just in case), sit on the desk and see if there is any swaying, bending, cracking (yikes!), etc. (If you are well under that weight, find a bigger friend to test it.) If that test works then I think you'll be fine, though if you really want to play it safe, I would roughly center the tank over one of the brackets. I've stood on desks like this to reach up to the ceiling to install cabling - and that's a more dynamic load than a tank (or a person) sitting there.

Comment: Have a kitchen cupboard that was on the wall(think a few screws missed the studs), very limited use.  One day after about 15/20 years, it just fell down.  It is the last time I look at a cupboard funny.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the weight of another whole adult…

Bearing in mind that at some point in time someone may also lean on it, even if not their full weight, but you really, really need some margin for error with two fish tanks & a computer - none of which are very keen on being suddenly dumped on the floor - I wouldn't consider it safe unless three people can sit on the front edge without it collapsing.

Your static weight needs to be good for two people, but you don't want to be anywhere near collapse if someone leans on it, so you have to allow for the weight of three. Absolute minimum, two adults & a child.
Yes, that's a lot of weight.

I also wouldn't trust it unless I knew the load-bearing capacity of the brackets, the fastenings up into the wood & whether it's solidly bolted back into brick/concrete.

If it's on just drywall or studs, forget it.

Comment: Rather than adding more brackets to the wall, if I buy some desk leg supports looking at steel ones which go to the floor and have a weight capacity of 150kg each so 2 would be 300kg which drill into the desk underneath would that work? Thanks

Comment: It might, depending on the existing wall fastenings. I'd still be inclined to sit three people on it before the fish tanks.